# No "message" signal from GstBus

Tags: gtk, gstreamer, vala

I'm writting some converter with Gstreamer-1.0 and vala-0.20 and Gtk+-3.0

I have noticed that I can't get any "message" from the bus of my pipeline,
because my signal handler is never called:

```
 public void job_add_on_click(GLib.Object but, void *data)
 {
    Gtk.Window win = ((but as Widget).get_toplevel()) as Gtk.Window;          
    TreeView tree = (data as TreeView);
    TreeModel model = tree.model;
    stdout.printf ("trctrc\n");
    ListStore store = (model as ListStore);
    FileChooserDialog dialog = new FileChooserDialog("Selectionner un fichier",
                                                     win, Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
                                                     Gtk.Stock.CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
                                                     Gtk.Stock.OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT, null);
    dialog.select_multiple = true;
    Dialog dial = dialog as Dialog;
    if(dial.run() != Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT)return;
        SList<File> lis = dialog.get_files();
        dialog.close ();
        Element decode = ElementFactory.make("decodebin","decode");
        Element src = ElementFactory.make("filesrc","src");
        Pipeline pipe = new Pipeline("pipe");
        Element pix = ElementFactory.make("autovideosink","pix");//gdkpixbufsink
        pipe.add_many(src, decode, pix);
        ForBus fb = new ForBus( store, tree, win, pipe);
        Gst.Bus b = pipe.get_bus();
        b.add_signal_watch();
        b.message.connect(fb.pix_watch_on_bus);
        src.link_pads("src", decode, "sink");
        GLib.Signal.connect(decode , "pad-added", (GLib.Callback)pad_add, (void *)pipe);
        uint len = lis.length();
        stdout.printf ("chacla\n");
        uint i = 0;
        int rm = 0;
        File file;
        string title, path;
        for(i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
            file = lis.nth_data(i);
            title = file.get_basename();
            path = file.get_path();
            fb.path = path;
            fb.title = title;
            string loc;
            src.set("location", path);
            src.get("location", out loc );
            stdout.printf ("location: %s\n", loc);
            stdout.printf ("path file: %s  title: %s\n", fb.path, fb.title);
                      stdout.printf ("state of pipe14 %s\n", pipe.current_state.to_string ());
            pipe.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING);
              pipe.get_state (null, null, Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE);
            stdout.printf ("change meme non\n");
            while(pipe.current_state != Gst.State.PAUSED)
            {
                Thread.usleep (2000000);
                stdout.printf ("state of pipe11 %s\n", pipe.current_state.to_string ());
            }
            stdout.printf ("%d fois\n", (int)i);
            pipe.set_state(Gst.State.NULL);
            fb.end_int = pipe.numchildren;
            for(rm = fb.start_int; rm < fb.end_int; rm++)
            {
                pipe.remove(pipe.get_by_name("sink".concat((rm).to_string())));
            }
        }
        b.remove_signal_watch();

    }

    public class ForBus: GLib.Object
    {
          public TreeIter iter;
          public ListStore store;
          public TreeView tree;
          public Gtk.Window win;
          public string path;
          public string title;
          public Pipeline pipe;
          public int start_int;
          public int end_int;
          public ForBus( ListStore store, TreeView tree, Gtk.Window win, Pipeline pip)
          {
              this.store = store;
              this.tree  = tree;
              this.win = win;
              this.pipe = pip;
              this.start_int = pipe.numchildren;
              stdout.printf ("creation pipe childreen %d", this.start_int);
          }
          public void pix_watch_on_bus(Gst.Bus bus, Gst.Message msg)
          {
             stdout.printf ("name message originator\n");
          }
    }

  public void pad_add(Element decode1, Pad new_pad, void* data)
    {
        stdout.printf ("not good I suppose hein\n");
        Gst.Pipeline pipe = data as Gst.Pipeline;
        stdout.printf ("it is good here\n");
        Caps actual_caps = new_pad.query_caps (null);
        if(actual_caps == null)stdout.printf ("this caaps is null\n");
        unowned Structure stru = actual_caps.get_structure(0);
                stdout.printf ("tictidddddddvvvvvc\n");
        stdout.printf ("name of pad %s\n", stru.get_name ());
        if(stru.get_name().has_prefix ("video/x-raw"))
        {
            stdout.printf ("video\n");
            Element pix = pipe.get_by_name("pix");
            if(pix == null)stdout.printf ("pix is null\n");
            Pad pad = pix.get_static_pad("sink");
            stdout.printf ("danger\n");
            if(pad.is_linked() == true)
            {
                stdout.printf ("audio\n");
                Element tmp = ElementFactory.make("alsa","sink".concat((pipe.numchildren).to_string()));
                Pad p = tmp.get_static_pad("sink");
                stdout.printf ("%d\n", pipe.numchildren);
                pipe.add(tmp);
                new_pad.link(p);
                tmp.sync_state_with_parent();
                return;
            }
            stdout.printf ("calcuta\n");
            new_pad.link(pad);
            stdout.printf ("do it ffff\n");
        stdout.printf ("state of pipe %s\n", pipe.current_state.to_string ());
            return;
        }
        Element tmp1 = ElementFactory.make("autoaudiosink","sink".concat((pipe.numchildren).to_string()));
        pipe.add(tmp1);
        stdout.printf ("%d\n", pipe.numchildren);
        Pad p1 = tmp1.get_static_pad("sink");
        new_pad.link(p1);
        stdout.printf ("sa data rek\n");
        stdout.printf ("end of\n");
        tmp1.sync_state_with_parent();
        stdout.printf ("with its parent\n");
        if(pipe.current_state==Gst.State.PLAYING)stdout.printf ("pipe is playing\n");
    }
```

All stdout.printf is for debugging purpose.

I use Gtk so there is mainloop behind this code.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `pipe` is probably going out of scope. Try using `object.signal.connect(...)` instead of `GLib.Signal.connect`, as per: https://wiki.gnome.org/Vala/SignalsAndCallbacks

If you have to use a `void*` in Vala, you're probably doing way more work than you should be, since Vala should have abstracted that with something more type-safe.

Comment: Hello apmasell I don't understand your answer because I suppose that my problem is between this 2 statements:                      b.add_signal_watch();
b.message.connect(fb.pix_watch_on_bus);    so what the link with my pipeline?  thanks

Comment: I was referring to the "pad-added". Either way, when is the pipeline supposed to run? GStreamer won't invoke one of your signals unless you return to the main loop. You need to have your pipeline live in a scope outside this function.

Comment: it lives outside this function because I can play some movies with it but I can't get any signal from its bus. The pipeline is supposed to run after setting it to a playing state from the job_add_on_click function...